# Best practices for building and packaging on AIX

Tags: c, compilation, aix

Does anyone know where i can find some best practices guide for building and packaging C applications on AIX.

I m using the xlc compiler and make.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [here](http://publibn.boulder.ibm.com/doc_link/en_US/a_doc_lib/aixprggd/genprogc/pkging_sw4_install.htm) ?